# Appcelerator Titanium, Dreamfactory and JSON to table

Tags: javascript, json, appcelerator

I'm currently working on a mobile version of my app on appcelerator (ex titanium).
I have a Dreamfactory server who provide me rest api functionality (fantastic product).

I need to put JSON sent by dreamfactory into a table. 
My request to the server is good as I can send the JSON into console with
`Ti.API.info(response.record);`.

Here is the request function:

```
dreamfactory.makeRequest("get","/mongoBit/partner").then(function(response) {     
    Ti.API.info(response.record);
    }, function(error){
        Ti.API.info(error);
});
```

So now I want to put the JSON into a table.
I've tried many solution found on Stack Overflow without any success.
Maybe someone here knows how to do it?

Comment: Can you add to your code an example of JSON output?